# Adding ID value to Subsequent Excel Data Exports to SQL Server Using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that inserts a new client record into SQL Server and retrieves the new Client ID into a variable defined in my package. I want to include the variable containing the new Client ID value when exporting subsequent Excel file data to SQL Server in the same package to create child records for that client in various tables. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You said you had it in a variable already.

Just use a derived column to add a column to your data set.

```
@VariableName
```